# OpenCV memory leak using cvCreateFileCapture and cvQueryFrame

Tags: c++, opencv, memory-leaks, video-capture

I am new to OpenCV (OpenCV 3.2 / opencv_ffmpeg320_64.dll / Windows 10 / Visual Studio 2017) and wrote a program dealing with a video stream of a webcam. Unfortunately the program has a memory leak. After hours of searching and googling I managed to break down the problem to the following minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <thread>

CvCapture *capture;
IplImage *frame;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    capture = cvCreateFileCapture("http://192.168.1.123:8080/CamStream");

    while (true)
    {
        cvWaitKey(1);

        frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
        if (frame)
        {
            std::cout << "New image" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see I am capturing of a simple HTTP stream. After the capture is created new frames are received. Unfortunately the task manager shows a never stopping increase of memory:

[image: Process]

What could cause this problem and what are possible approaches to solve it?

Comment: If this is C++, why use the old C API? Right now you have to manage pointers yourself, which often leads to problems. | However, other than not releasing the `capture` instance, I don't see any obvious leaks (the frame pointer returned by `cvQueryFrame` ought to be owned by OpenCV.)

Comment: BTW, which VideoCapture backend is it using? Can you reproduce it reading a video file? Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your help @DanMašek . I am using Visual Studio 2017 with the opencv_ffmpeg320_64.dll. I am not able to reproduce the problem using a video file (the memory consumption remains constant).

Comment: Well, looks like [you're not alone](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20leak) with this problem.

Comment: Oh dear .. looks like this problem is still unsolved since many months ... it's frustrating.